# OpenVPN route-up script after trusted

Tags: linux, openvpn

I am trying to execute a client connection script from my OpenVPN server that will work AFTER the peer is trusted. I.E. I want to be able to ping the client address after the tunnel is fully established. Currently, it seems with `client-connect` or `route-up`, the peer has an IP address but it is unpingable. what is the best way to allow my server to automatically interact with clients upon initial connection to the server?